# SqLite replace method trims in presence of multiple carriage returns whole part of the text instead of carriage returns

Tags: replace, sqlite

I want to trim some carriage returns in a SqLite Database through the SqLite command line. 
For example (in Line Mode):

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM my_table;

Id = 10
description = a carriage return here ->
              another carriage return here ->
              rest of the text.
```

So i want to trim the carriage return to get something like this (Line mode):

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM my_table;

Id = 10
description = a carriage return here -> another carriage return here -> rest of the text.
```

I tried this:

```
sqlite> UPDATE my_table SET description=REPLACE(description,x'0A','');
```

which produces this (line Mode):

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM my_table;

Id = 10
rest of the text.
```

This is no joke, there is no 'description =' anymore and in the list mode it looks like this:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM my_table;

rest of the text.
```

No Id anymore.

Any ideas why this happens? If there's just one carriage return, everything is fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS-DOS line endings consist of two control characters with values 13 and 10.

13 is "carriage return", which returns the cursor to the start of the current line.
10 is "line feed", which moves the cursor one line down.

On Unix systems, control character 10 combines both actions. Character 13 is not needed, but if it is actually used, it still works.

When you have MS-DOS line endings and remove only the characters with value 10, the remaining control characters will cause everything after a line end to overwrite the previous line.

You should remove both control characters:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET description = REPLACE(REPLACE(description, x'0A', ''), x'0D', '')
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. This does the Job. And a great description what happens, too.